# Youtube iframe videos do not work in react-native webview

Tags: android, react-native, youtube-api, android-webview, instagram-api

I have a problem with playing youtube or instagram videos wrapped inside iframe using react-native-webview. The problem is only in Android. IOS works fine.

So, when i put iframe into webview it looks ok. Until I click on play button. Video starts loading, all native buttons are available and sound works fine but the movie is black. Sound and stop/play buttons work.

Dependencies:

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.57.5
"react-native-webview": "^2.12.1"
```

I prepared simple demo where the videos do not work:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        useWebKit={false}
        source={{
          html: `
          XX
          <div>
            <iframe width="320" height="240" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/li8yILhFFZM" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe> 
          </div> `

        }}
      />

    );
  }
}
```

and screenshot of the problem:

[image]

Thank you for help!

Comment: In Android Manifest file just include `hardwareAccelerated=true`. Then the black screen issue will be solved.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative you can use URI simply with default webview from react-native ,works well with android.

```
   <View style={styles.cardRounded}>
    <WebView
      mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={true}
      style={{ height:240, width:320,alignSelf:"center",alignContent:"center"}}
      source={{uri: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/li8yILhFFZM?rel=0' }}
    />
   </View>

let styles = StyleSheet.create({
    cardRounded: {
        paddingEnd:0,  paddingTop: 0 , paddingBottom: 0, paddingStart: 0, padding:0,
        borderRadius: 12, alignItems:"center", backgroundColor:#000000,flex:0, height:240,
    },

});
```

Answer (score 0):

For me setting `androidLayerType="hardware"` or `androidLayerType="none"` (*which is the default*) did the job

```js
<WebView
  // ...
  androidLayerType="hardware" // <-- Add this or androidLayerType="none"
  // ...     
/>
```

but, I had to remove `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` in the activity of *./android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml* (if it was present).

*P.S.: This does cause the app to randomly close on navigation from the screen containing the iFrame.*

*P.P.S.: Checkout this [issue](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/172) for more info.*